# Generating files in Docker vs. Docker Compose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am learning Docker and have a little confusion that I would greatly appreciate some advice on.

When creating a new rails application. Following the guidelines of Docker's tutorial [Quickstart: Compose & Rails](https://docs.docker.com/samples/rails/). They're steps are as follows.

1. Create Dockerfile & Entrypoint
2. Create Gemfile with source and rails gem listed.
3. Create an empty Gemfile.lock
4. Create a docker-compose.yml and name services.
5. Generate a new rails app using docker-compose run.

The rails new command.

```
docker-compose run --no-deps web rails new . --force -d mysql
```

This is my simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:3.1.1-alpine3.15

RUN apk update -q
RUN apk add bash yarn git build-base nodejs mariadb-dev tzdata

WORKDIR /app

COPY Gemfile /app/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /app/Gemfile.lock

COPY package.json /app/package.json
COPY yarn.lock /app/yarn.lock

RUN gem install bundler
RUN gem update bundler
RUN bundle install

COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 3000
```

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

As you can see I only have one service listed in my docker-compose.yml, because I do not want any other services or containers.

Everything works fine when I use the command docker-compose run rails new ... it generates a new rails app and persists the files to my local source folder. So I can open and edit the files to develop the application. Perfect.

But when I try and generate a new Rails app without using docker-compose.yml and only the Dockerfile. The generated files are not persisted in my local source folder, only on the container. I can only assume because I am forced to build the image before running it in a container to generate the new rails app.

When using without docker-compose.yml. I have to build the image first.

```
docker build -t image_name .
```

Then I can run the container and generate the rails app.

```
docker run image_name rails new . --force -d mysql
```

Obviously, this doesn't persit the new files in my local source folder.

**How can I generate a new Rails app with just my Dockerfile without docker compose and still have the newly generated files persist in my local source folder?**

I must be missing something, but I've done a lot of research and can't find an answer.

Comment: The workflow you're looking at will force you to prefix basically _every_ command you might want to run with `docker-compose run ...` (possibly requiring `sudo` as well).  This has always struck me as inconvenient at best.  Can you use a tool like [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) to get a local Ruby environment outside of Docker (and so you can directly `bundle exec rails ...`), and use Docker (without the `volumes:` or `command:` overrides) for integration testing and deployment?

Comment: I may be wrong in this. But I wanted to utilize Docker as a development environment and a production tool. Wouldn't using rbenv locally contradict this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In docker-compose.yml you have a 'volumes' key as seen below.

```
volumes:
  - .:/app
```

But when using it in the CLI you miss passing these volumes.

You can pass these volumes as in the code below.

```
docker run -d --name=rails --volume /your/workdir:/app image_name
```

If you want to learn more about volumes, you can find out [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I ran your commands and was able to reproduce the result.